# Bootstrap navbar stopping ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-view

I'm trying to build a angular application with node.js and jade. Here's the relevant code

```
block body
 div(ng-controller='AppCtrl')
   .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top(role='navigation')
     .container
       .navbar-header
         button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='.navbar-collapse')
           span.sr-only Toggle navigation
           span.icon-bar
           span.icon-bar
           span.icon-bar
        a.navbar-brand(href='/') Halló {{name}}
       .navbar-collapse.collapse
         ul.nav.navbar-nav
           li.active
             a(href='/frettir') Fréttir
           li
             a(href='/dagskra') Dagskrá
           li
             a(href='/skaramuss') Skaramúss
   div(ng-view)
```

And then ng-view doesn't work. But when I comment out the navbar the ng-view works. What am I doing wrong?